# SVG floating out it's Anchor container

Tags: html, css, containers, overflow, anchor

**How can I fix the <a> and make it contain all the SVG icon.**
and also plz plz, **How to remove the underline area of the <a> element??**
[photo for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxEjz.png)

```css
a {
  background-color: rgba(42, 165, 42, 0.596);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

svg {
  background-color: rgba(165, 42, 42, 0.596);
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16.28 16.28">
        <path
          d="M8.14 3.96a4.17 4.17 0 0 0-4.17 4.17 4.16 4.16 0 0 0 4.17 4.17 4.17 4.17 0 0 0 4.17-4.17A4.17 4.17 0 0 0 8.2 3.96zm0 6.88a2.71 2.71 0 1 1 0-5.42 2.71 2.71 0 0 1 2.71 2.71 2.72 2.72 0 0 1-2.71 2.72zm5.32-7a1 1 0 0 1-1.707.707 1 1 0 0 1 .707-1.707 1 1 0 0 1 1 1zm2.76 1a4.83 4.83 0 0 0-1.32-3.4A4.84 4.84 0 0 0 11.49.12a107.23 107.23 0 0 0-6.71 0 4.87 4.87 0 0 0-3.41 1.31A4.86 4.86 0 0 0 .05 4.84a107.55 107.55 0 0 0 0 6.72 4.86 4.86 0 0 0 1.32 3.41 4.79 4.79 0 0 0 3.41 1.23c1.34.08 5.37.08 6.71 0a4.79 4.79 0 0 0 3.41-1.3 4.86 4.86 0 0 0 1.3-3.41c.08-1.34.08-5.37 0-6.71zM14.48 13a2.76 2.76 0 0 1-1.54 1.55c-1.07.42-3.62.32-4.8.32s-3.73.1-4.8-.32A2.75 2.75 0 0 1 1.79 13c-.43-1.07-.33-3.62-.33-4.8s-.09-3.73.33-4.8a2.73 2.73 0 0 1 1.55-1.54c1.07-.43 3.61-.33 4.8-.33s3.73-.1 4.8.32a2.75 2.75 0 0 1 1.55 1.55c.42 1.07.32 3.62.32 4.8s.1 3.73-.33 4.8z"
        />
      </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: I can understand you need to remove green line, but what you mean by *"How can I fix the <a> and make it contain all the SVG icon."*

Comment: I meant is the  display: inline-block; is best way to make the anchor element contain all svg inside it

Comment: Modern flex is the best way, it supports all types of arrangements you need in any case. So, try to use `inline-flex`, even that's the answer I have provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG icon is *50px* X *50px*, but since the `a` is usually a *inline* element it gives some extra space,
Just like a text which is an inline element, that gives *space up, and down*
This causes the browser to think that ,`svg` which is inside `a` is an inline element, and gives space.
To perfectly make the `a` element's width and height equal to `svg`

- Add `display: inline-flex` to parent's(`a`) css
- Add `display: inline-table` to child's(`svg`) css

### Example snippet

```css
a {
  background-color: rgba(42, 165, 42, 0.596);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

svg {
  background-color: rgba(165, 42, 42, 0.596);
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16.28 16.28">
        <path
          d="M8.14 3.96a4.17 4.17 0 0 0-4.17 4.17 4.16 4.16 0 0 0 4.17 4.17 4.17 4.17 0 0 0 4.17-4.17A4.17 4.17 0 0 0 8.2 3.96zm0 6.88a2.71 2.71 0 1 1 0-5.42 2.71 2.71 0 0 1 2.71 2.71 2.72 2.72 0 0 1-2.71 2.72zm5.32-7a1 1 0 0 1-1.707.707 1 1 0 0 1 .707-1.707 1 1 0 0 1 1 1zm2.76 1a4.83 4.83 0 0 0-1.32-3.4A4.84 4.84 0 0 0 11.49.12a107.23 107.23 0 0 0-6.71 0 4.87 4.87 0 0 0-3.41 1.31A4.86 4.86 0 0 0 .05 4.84a107.55 107.55 0 0 0 0 6.72 4.86 4.86 0 0 0 1.32 3.41 4.79 4.79 0 0 0 3.41 1.23c1.34.08 5.37.08 6.71 0a4.79 4.79 0 0 0 3.41-1.3 4.86 4.86 0 0 0 1.3-3.41c.08-1.34.08-5.37 0-6.71zM14.48 13a2.76 2.76 0 0 1-1.54 1.55c-1.07.42-3.62.32-4.8.32s-3.73.1-4.8-.32A2.75 2.75 0 0 1 1.79 13c-.43-1.07-.33-3.62-.33-4.8s-.09-3.73.33-4.8a2.73 2.73 0 0 1 1.55-1.54c1.07-.43 3.61-.33 4.8-.33s3.73-.1 4.8.32a2.75 2.75 0 0 1 1.55 1.55c.42 1.07.32 3.62.32 4.8s.1 3.73-.33 4.8z"
        />
      </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: I only added  display: inline-flex; for the a element
and it seems to fix the problem, so why should i add the display: inline-table; for the svg ??

Comment: Yes but when you have multiple elements, and you want to arrange them in opposite direction(horizontal to vertical),you may have problem(For certain scenario), So I added it as precaution

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: yes thank you alot